# Где утечка и как от нее избавиться?

Tags: c++

Дали вот такой код на собеседовании:

```
class A()
{
  A() {
    this.p = new int[20];
  }
};

class B: public A
{
  B() {
    this.c = new double[50];
  }
};

A *pt = new B();
delete pt;
```

1. Сказали, что есть серьезная утечка. К сожалению, не хватило опыта, чтобы точно ответить на вопрос. Прошу вашей помощи. Придираться к синтаксическим ошибкам или опечаткам нельзя.
   Хочу закрепить свои знания и закрыть пробелы. Прошу вашей помощи.
2. Двоеточие на 8-й строке при объявлении класса. Из какой оперы? (Хочу изучить эту тему)
   Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Преобразовал в ответ.
Скорее всего, p и c  это члены классов А и B соответственно. Тестируемый скорее всего хотел, чтобы пациент нашел, что объект B приводится к типу объекта A и, соответственно, при разрушении pt вызовется деструктор класса A, а деструктор B - нет

Comment: Ну и добавьте решение: в бызовом классе нужно всегда объявлять деструктор виртуальным.

Answer (score 5):

1. Строкой `delete pt;` вы освобождаете только память, выделенную под объект `pt`. В неё входит только память, выделенная под указатели `p` и `c` (кстати, где они объявлены?) и не входит память, выделенная под массивы, повешенные на эти указатели. Нужно написать деструкторы для классов `A` и `B`, освобождающие выделенную под массивы память.
2. Это из оперы "Наследование". Одна из основных концепций ООП.

Answer (score 1):

Из книги Прата "Язык программирования с++", стр. 690 внизу.

> Если виртуальный метод вызывается через ссылку или указатель на объект, то 
> программа использует метод, определенный для типа объекта, а не для типа 
> указателя или ссылки. Это называется динамическим (или поздним) связыванием. 
> Такое поведение очень важно, т.к. указатель или ссылка на базовый класс всегда 
> может обратиться к объекту производного типа.

Совершенно согласен с renegator